# Excel VBA code to check if cell blank based on another cell's data

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I have a spreadsheet that multiple users fill out and turn in daily.  In this spreadsheet there are three separate Yes/No questions.  If they enter Yes, then in the following column they have to enter data.  I want to make a VBA code to check and make sure this data is entered so we don't have to keep sending the spreadsheets back to the users to fill in missing data.

My data is set up like this:  K12:K111, N12:N111, and P12:P111 are all the Yes/No columns while L12:L111, O12:O111, and Q12:Q111 are the cells that require text ONLY if a "Yes" was put in the K, N or P columns.  Could someone help me with the coding for this?

I would ideally like to put an ActiveX button on the spreadsheet to run the VBA code if possible.  I would also like for it to show a dialog box telling which cells need data entered.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:  I did change the Ranges from M to N as I had misspoken in my original post.  I used the code suggested below and am getting a Compile Error: Invalid inside procedure.  This is how I pasted it in to correspond to the button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim rngK As Range, rngN As Range, rngP As Range, cell As Range
    Dim Counter As Long

    Counter = 0

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set rngK = .Range("K12:K111")
        Set rngN = .Range("N12:N111")
        Set rngP = .Range("P12:P111")

        For Each cell In rngK

            If cell.Value = "Yes" And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then

                cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
                Counter = Counter + 1

            End If

        Next cell

        For Each cell In rngN

            If cell.Value = "Yes" And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then

                cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
                Counter = Counter + 1

            End If

        Next cell

        For Each cell In rngP

            If cell.Value = "Yes" And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then

                cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
                Counter = Counter + 1

            End If

        Next cell

        If Counter > 0 Then

            MsgBox "Please fill red highlighted fields!"

        End If

    End With

End Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add your current code and explain where you are having difficulties with it.

Comment: I am using the code from "Error 4004" below, but I pasted it in for an activeX button that I put on the sheet.  The first line is Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() and it is giving me an error at that position when I click the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim rngK As Range, rngM As Range, rngP As Range, cell As Range
    Dim Counter As Long

    Counter = 0

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set rngK = .Range("K12:K111")
        Set rngM = .Range("M12:M111")
        Set rngP = .Range("P12:P111")

        For Each cell In rngK

            If cell.Value = "Yes" And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then

                cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
                Counter = Counter + 1

            End If

        Next cell

        For Each cell In rngM

            If cell.Value = "Yes" And cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "" Then

                cell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = vbRed
                Counter = Counter + 1

            End If

        Next cell

        For Each cell In rngP

            If cell.Value = "Yes" And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then

                cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
                Counter = Counter + 1

            End If

        Next cell

        If Counter > 0 Then

            MsgBox "Please fill red highlighted fields!"

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

As per OP request:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("K12:K111, M12:M111,P12:P111")) Is Nothing Then

        With Target

            If UCase(.Value) = "YES" Then
                .Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
            Else
                .Offset(0, 1).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            End If

        End With

    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("L12:L111, O12:O111,Q12:Q111")) Is Nothing Then

        With Target

            If .Value = "" And UCase(.Offset(0, -1).Value) = "YES" Then
                .Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
            Else
                .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            End If

        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!  I realized I should have put the above code in a module, then have the button activate the module, and after I did that and renamed the sheet in the code to match, it worked.  The only other question I have is after they enter something in the fields can the same button or module also remove the shading if there are no blank fields?